# Two <p:confirmDialog> in one xhtml

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, xhtml

I have two  in one xhtml. But both of them are not working properly.
When I click the Save button, the confirmDialog of the Import button came up.
When I click the Import button, nothing came up.
Is there anything that I have missed out?

```
               <td><p:commandButton type="button"
                 value="Save" id="cr1002_command_save"
                 onclick="confirmation.show()" ajax="false"
                 style="width: 80px;height: 24px">
              </p:commandButton> <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog"
                 message="#{msg.cr1002_prompt_confirm_save}" severity="alert"
                 widgetVar="confirmation" style="width: 70px;height: 27px">
                 <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="OK"
                    oncomplete="confirmation.hide()"
                    action="#{pc_Cr1002.doCr1002_command_saveAction}" ajax="false"
                    style="width: 80px;height: 24px" />
                 <p:commandButton id="decline" value="Cancel"
                    onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button"
                    style="width: 80px;height: 24px" />
              </p:confirmDialog></td>
           <td></td>
           <td><p:commandButton type="button"
                 value="Import"
                 onclick="gowait('form1:cr1002_command_import')"
                 id="cr1002_command_import" ajax="false"
                 style="width: 80px;height: 24px"></p:commandButton>
                  <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog2"
                 message="Importing... Importing..." severity="alert"
                 widgetVar="confirmation" style="width: 70px;height: 27px">
                 <p:commandButton id="confirm2" value="OK"
                    oncomplete="confirmation.hide()"
                    action="#{pc_Cr1002.doCr1002_command_importAction}" ajax="false"
                    style="width: 80px;height: 24px" />
                 <p:commandButton id="decline2" value="Cancel"
                    onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button"
                    style="width: 80px;height: 24px" />
              </p:confirmDialog>
           </td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem come from the same `widgetVar attribute`, this attribute use in client side, it cause conflict in client side, you should code like as:

```
<td><p:commandButton type="button"
                 value="Save" id="cr1002_command_save"
                 onclick="confirmation.show()" ajax="false"
                 style="width: 80px;height: 24px">
              </p:commandButton> <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog"
                 message="#{msg.cr1002_prompt_confirm_save}" severity="alert"
                 widgetVar="confirmation" style="width: 70px;height: 27px">
                 <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="OK"
                    oncomplete="confirmation.hide()"
                    action="#{pc_Cr1002.doCr1002_command_saveAction}" ajax="false"
                    style="width: 80px;height: 24px" />
                 <p:commandButton id="decline" value="Cancel"
                    onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button"
                    style="width: 80px;height: 24px" />
              </p:confirmDialog></td>
           <td></td>
           <td><p:commandButton type="button"
                 value="Import"
                 onclick="confirmation2.show()"
                 id="cr1002_command_import" ajax="false"
                 style="width: 80px;height: 24px"></p:commandButton>
                  <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog2"
                 message="Importing... Importing..." severity="alert"
                 widgetVar="confirmation2" style="width: 70px;height: 27px">
                 <p:commandButton id="confirm2" value="OK"
                    oncomplete="confirmation.hide()"
                    action="#{pc_Cr1002.doCr1002_command_importAction}" ajax="false"
                    style="width: 80px;height: 24px" />
                 <p:commandButton id="decline2" value="Cancel"
                    onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button"
                    style="width: 80px;height: 24px" />
              </p:confirmDialog>
           </td>
```

Comment: @hahagal You are welcome, you should mark as answer to close your question !